# non functional requirements dataset

Tags: nlp, classification

I am developing a machine learning project which analyzes requirement specification and categorizes the non-functional requirements into categories like database, web socket, backend technology, etc. I'm planning to use topic modeling and LDA to categorize into these categorizes but I wasn't able to find a proper dataset for this. If someone can help me out, I would highly appreciate this. Training data set for Software Quality Requirements (Non-Functional Requirements).

Comment: I have found out that many researches have used PROMISE dataset, but the link provided in research papers are removed. Can someone comment the new link to that dataset?